Is it correct to omit the subject in the subordinate clause?
I am a first time asker)
Can we say so?

The teacher told the class hadn't had time to check their papers yet.

Can we omit he here?
PS: Our teacher requested us to complete an online test. One of its sentences read: the teacher told the class (not have) time lalala. I opened the verb in the Past perfect but why is he missing? Is it a mistake of smb who compiled the test?

Please use the "edit" button to explain more about why you think this could be okay. It's not; you need "he"; but that's not a very useful answer.

Thanks, Andy. My gratitude knows no bounds.

My first interpretation was that the teacher told [someone] that the class hadn't had time to check their [own] papers, so I thought "Why he?" Then I realised that, of course, it was the teacher who hadn't checked the papers.

Yes, if the test allowed only a verb in between "class" and "time," it was a mistake.
Why? This sentence is a bit complicated. The main part is just "The teacher told the class." That's simple enough. It sets up "reported speech": What did they tell the class? What follows is a simple declarative clause; it could stand on its own as a sentence, and it needs a subject.
You could have gotten away with no extra subject in a sentence like "The teacher told the class not to cheat", in which the rest of the sentence is dependent and can't stand on its own.

I agree with you. It should have read: The teacher told the class HE hadn't had time to check their papers yet. The guy must have omitted he by mistake.
